# What is this blueprint that Zola grabs?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In the First Avenger, when Capt storms the base and frees the captured part of the 107th Regiment, the Red Skull sets the auto-destruct for the base. This causes Dr. Zola to scramble to grab some paperwork before running. One of the things he grabs is this blueprint. What is this blueprint of?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### It seems to be a blueprint to his Robot Body.

In the comics ([**Wikia**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Arnim_Zola's_Robotic_Body))

> Needing funds to continue his research, Arnim Zola presented his first invention, the creation of device that would transfer someone's essence to a cloned body, to Adolf Hitler, who agreed to become his patron. This device and partnership allowed Hitler to survive World War II as the Hate-Monger. Zola also used it on himself, not only allowing him to survive into modern times but to also replace his normally frail body with a stronger, android one. This robot body allowed bipedal movement and projected an image of his original face on a screen located on it's chest.

In the movies...

> Arnim Zola continued to work for the Allies, eventually becoming part of S.H.I.E.L.D. upon the organization's formation. After receiving a "terminal diagnosis" in 1972, Zola found a way to preserve his brain patterns via computer tape, and transcended death as an artificial intelligence. In the present day, Captain America and Black Widow discovered the secret complex within a bunker at Camp Lehigh where the computers containing Zola are kept, and learned from him that Hydra still existed as a conspiracy with a major branch within S.H.I.E.L.D.

**So we might see this Robot Body yet!**

[image]